# Dyanmically enable/disable and populate options to mat-select in angular 5

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, html-select, angular-services

I have 2 mat-select tags in my angular application. One is to choose a domain and another is to choose a company. The structure of domain is

```
export class Domain {
    domainname : string;
}
```

The structure of company is

```
export class Company {
    companyname : string;
    domains : Domain[];
}
```

Each company can operate in one or more domains. For now, i have stored all companies and domains as constants in typescript files and have written services to fetch them.

Initially when the view loads, i want the company select tag to be disabled. Only when a domain is selected from the domain select tag, the company select tag should be enabled and populated with companies that operate in that domain. Every time i change my selection in the domain select tag, it should automatically repopulate the options with the corresponding companies that operate in that domain. I am currently facing 2 issues

1. I have tried to fetch companies by domain value using the filter function but can't seem to get it right (I am completly new to Javascript/Typescript). Here is the code for my company service (CompanyList is a const 'Company' array)

```js
@Injectable()
export class CompanyService {

  constructor() { }

  getAllCompanies() : Company[] {
    return CompanyList;
  }
  
  getCompaniesByDomain(dom : string) : Company[] {
    return CompanyList.filter((company)=> {company.domains.find(dom)});
  }
  
}
```

2. The ng-disabled tag that i've added at the company select, is giving me errors. I have tried multiple variations of it but none of them seem to work. This is my typescript & html code :

```js
export class DashHeaderComponent implements OnInit {

  domainList : Domain[];

  companyList : Company[];

  selecteddomain : string;

  constructor(private domainService : DomainService, private companyService : CompanyService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.domainList = this.domainService.getDomainList();
    this.companyList = this.companyService.getCompaniesByDomain(selecteddomain);
    this.selecteddomain = "";
  }

  onDomainSelect(){
    //
  }

}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-dark navbar-custom" >   
 <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Logo</a>
 <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarTogglerDemo01" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo01"
    aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>           
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo01">
    <span class="flex-spacer"></span>       
    <mat-form-field class="select-space">
      <label for="domain-select">Select Domain</label>   
      <mat-select id="domain-select" [(ngModel)]="selecteddomain" ng-change="onDomainSelect()">                
        <mat-option *ngFor="let domain of domainList" [value]="domain.domainname">{{domain.domainname}}</mat-option>
      </mat-select>    
    </mat-form-field>      
    <mat-form-field class="select-space">
      <label for="company-select">Compare</label>  
      <mat-select multiple id="company-select" ng-disabled="selecteddomain === """>
        <mat-option *ngFor="let company of companyList" [value]="company.companyname">{{company.companyname}}</mat-option>
      </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
  </div>       
</nav>
```

The code is currently incomplete but i would like to know what am i doing wrong in the above 2 scenarios? TIA

Comment: In your DashHeaderComponent  use this to access property like :
this.companyService.getCompaniesByDomain(this.selecteddomain);